# how do i prevent one user open online test in two browser at same time

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am developing an online test with asp.net.

One user after sign up can take online test. 
But she/he can browse online test with different browser in same time that I want to prevent of it.

I cannot prevent of entrance of user after start test because user can take exam in test time limit after start test (even user can close the browser and enters again until his test time limit time out)

How do I realize one user enter one exam with two browser at same time?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435793/how-do-i-stop-multiple-user-login-with-same-email-and-password-once-user-already will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should catch the IP of him/her and use a token system too. Anyway I think you should   check this too : [how to prevent user from using multiple browsers at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301074/how-to-prevent-user-from-using-multiple-browsers-at-a-time)

Best Regards A.V